# Wolfram alpha and floating point arithmetic (loss of significance)

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, numerical-analysis

I'm studying floating point aritmetic. Suppose we are in double precision. We know that when we  subtract two numbers which has "almost" the same magnitude, the relative error is large.

In MatLab command window, for instance, if I compute

`2.0000001-2.0`

I obtain `9.99999998363421e-08`

and with a **relative error**  `errRel =  1.63657882716964e-09` which is not negligible.

But If I do that in Wolfram alpha (or with the calculator of my laptop), I actually obtain the right result, which is `1e-7`.

So, my **question** is: *why is that? I thought that both MatLab and the calculator of my laptop used the floating point arithmetic in the same way*

Comment: What does matlab have to do with wolfram alpha?

Comment: I don't think it is publicly documented what wolfram-alpha uses "under the hood", but they likely use some form of arbitrary-precision math.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible causes of seeing exactly 1e-7 on subtracting 2.0000001-2.0.

One is that many systems round to a reasonable number of digits on output. The exact conversion to decimal of IEEE 64-bit binary 2.0000001-2.0 is 9.9999999836342112757847644388675689697265625E-8. Some systems round to a limited number of significant digits, and might print that as 1e-7. On the other hand, Java, for example, delivers by default enough digits to distinguish the original value from any other double, and prints 9.999999983634211E-8

The other possible cause is if the arithmetic is being done in decimal, in which case the real numbers 2.0000001, 2, and their difference are all exactly representable because they are all decimal fractions. You would need to calculate something like 1/3 to see rounding error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your opinion, is it possible that the calculator of my laptop uses the arithmetic in decimal? It seems a bit weird to me

Comment: @lukk No easy way to distinguish. Perhaps try some calculations that need rounding in decimal, such as sqrt(2), 1/3, and 2/3. That may give some clues.

Comment: First of all, I've seen it uses single precision, since if I do 2/3 I obtain 0,666666667.
So, since 6 > (10)/2=5, then the last digit is rounded as 6+1 = 7, therefore it seems to use the decimal arithmetic. Is this a good way to confirm my suspect?

Comment: @lukk It is not using 32-bit IEEE 754. The exact value of 2.0f/3.0f is 0.666666686534881591796875. Rounded to the 9 decimal places it is displaying you would see 0.666666687.

Comment: Now try `1+1e-9-1`. If it is doing decimal arithmetic I would expect 1e-9. If it is doing IEEE 64-bit arithmetic I would expect 1.000000082740371E-9, rounded to the display width.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! :) I just got 1e-9. So it seems that it's using decimal arithmetic. Because if it wouldn't, I would expect the number you wrote in IEEE 64-bit arithmetic, right?

Comment: No, it only means not IEEE 754 64-bit binary. It could be decimal. It could be a higher precision binary system.